# min-height: auto not working in Opera

Tags: css, opera

I have noticed that `min-height` is not working in Opera. I am trying something like this:

```
<div class="content"><div>
<div class="content newstyle"><div>
```

And my CSS code is:

```
.content {
    min-height: 600px;
}
.newstyle {
    min-height: auto;
}
```

And Opera just acts like `min-height` didn't exist.
If I apply any other style in `.newstyle`, like background or whatever, then it works well. But `min-height: auto` seems not to work...

Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[CSS2.1 defines the initial value of `min-height` to be `0`, not `auto`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights) The value `auto` never existed in CSS2.1, so it is invalid in CSS2.1. Just use `min-height: 0` instead:

```
.content {
    min-height: 600px;
}
.newstyle {
    min-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: It has since been removed from the Flexbox module and that TR link anchor, #min-size-auto is no longer valid.

Comment: @danorton: Thanks, I've removed the flexbox reference entirely.

Comment: For those searching, same thing will occur in Safari. The slightly annoying thing is if you're developing in eg. Chrome, you won't notice because Chrome permissably allows you to still use auto. :)

Answer (score 6):

`auto;` is not a valid `value` for `min-height` property and hence Opera ignores...

You can specify `min-height` using `px`, `cm` etc, or `%` or `inherit`

[Sitepoint Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-height)

Comment: And what if i just dont want to establish a min-height but i want to ignore the other style min-height?

Comment: @BoltClock nah I don't think `auto` is valid

Comment: @Steve didn't got you and btw you don't need to use `min-height: auto;` as your div height is is auto by default unless and until you give the div some height

Comment: min-height:0 It's ok. Stupid of me :) Thanks!

Comment: @BoltClock whats the use of `min-height: 0`? cuz browser default height of div's is set to auto

Comment: @Mr. Alien: He wants to reset `min-height` to the default value, and that value is 0. Remember that we're talking about `min-height`, not `height` - they're two different things.

Comment: @BoltClock ya right, but what happens if am setting min-height to 0? anyways it's height will be 0 even if I don't specify

Comment: In the HTML, the `.content` class is on both divs, and he wants to reset it for `.newstyle`.

Comment: @BoltClock ya this is great when you want to RESET