# Doesn`t wokring min-height style

Tags: html, css

Im using Google Crome and I would set auto `min-height` style in this button:

```
<button style="padding: 0; min-height: auto" 
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</button>
```

why auto doesnt work? 0 or 100% doesnt works to

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my understanding u cant set `min-height: auto` it has to be some integer like 10px or something

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070456/min-height-auto-not-working-in-opera#answer-13070633)

[CSS2.1 defines the initial value of min-height to be 0](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights), not auto. The value auto never existed in CSS2.1, so it is invalid in CSS2.1. Just use min-height: 0 instead:

You can specify min-height using px, cm etc, or % or inherit

Answer (score 1):

`auto` doesn't work for min-height You must specify the minimum height. although auto works for `height` property